# Sum of Range of Numbers

Tags: haskell, recursion

Write a function called `rangeSum` that takes two integers, and returns the sum of all integers from the first to the second, inclusive. I haven’t defined what the function will do if the second argument is larger, like for the case of `rangeSum 5 3` . What would be sensible behaviour here?

This is the code that I've written so far:

```
rangeSum :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
rangeSum x y 
   | x == y = 0 
   | x > y  = error "rangeSum: First number cannot be bigger than the second number"
   | otherwise = undefined
```

I don't know what to replace `undefined` with

Comment: Hint: 3 + 4 + 5 + ... + _y_ = 3 + (4 + 5 + ... + _y_).

Comment: See @leftaroundabout's hint above. In the same spirit for the x > y case, 3 + 4 + 5 = 5 + 4 + 3

Comment: Are you permitted to use smarty-pants answers? Then you can also do the Gauss shortcut of calculating the sum of the first and last element, and multiplying this sum by the half of the amount of numbers. https://www.nctm.org/Publications/Teaching-Children-Mathematics/Blog/The-Story-of-Gauss/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead `undefined` in your code you can write `sum [x..y]`.

Also when `x > y` you can return `sum [y..x]`.

However, if you want to underline that `x` must not be greater than `y`, you can return a value of type `Maybe Integer` instead just `Integer`, so you can return `Nothing` if `x > y` and `Just $ sum [x..y]` otherwise.

So, your code can be like this:

```hs
rangeSum :: Integer -> Integer -> Maybe Integer
rangeSum x y 
   | x > y  = Nothing
   | otherwise = Just $ sum [x..y]
```

You can also solve this problem with recursion:

```hs
rangeSum :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
rangeSum x y
   | x == y = 0
   | x > y  = error "..."
   | otherwise = x + rangeSum (x+1) y
```

... or ...:

```hs
rangeSum :: Integer -> Integer -> Maybe Integer
rangeSum x y
   | x > y  = Nothing
   | otherwise = let
       helper x y | x == y = 0
       helper x y = x + helper (x+1) y in
       Just $ helper x y
```

Comment: That definitely helps in solving the problem but is there a way to possibly use recursion to solve it ?